# Compare two lists of string using java stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have two lists A and B. both have millions of elements. I want to compare and get all elements those are in list A but not in list B. Below is inefficient way to get elements.

```
   if (!B.containsAll(A)) {
        for (Integer id : A) {
            if (!B.contains(id)) {
                System.out.println(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

I looking for an efficient way with or without streams to get elements

help is appreciated in this regards.

Thanks

Comment: Use sets. [Hashsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) can check containment very quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterating and filtering two lists using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490418/iterating-and-filtering-two-lists-using-java-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to compare

```
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(a);
c.removeAll(b);
```

And if you don't mind loosing the original list data

```
a.removeAll(b);
```

Comment: Depending on the sizes of the input lists it might be more efficient to create a `Set` instead of an `ArrayList` (but not necessarily, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671903/hashset-removeall-method-is-surprisingly-slow). Either way, while this is a simple and readable approach, it first creates a full copy of a list containing "millions of elements".

Comment: @Hulk It isn't necessary to create the copy if you don't mind loosing the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should suffice:

```
Set<Integer> container = new HashSet<>(ListB);
ListA.stream()
     .filter(id -> !container.contains(id))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or non-stream:

```
Set<Integer> container = new HashSet<>(ListB);
for(Integer id : ListA)
    if(!container.contains(id));
       System.out.println(id);
```