# Update element on one list on matching particular element from another list

Tags: java

I want help in below query,

I have 2 lists.

1)Person with attributes: name, age, address, phone.

2)Account with attributes: accHolderName, type, age, address.

I want to set age, address of Person from Account if person's name is present in Account List.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried:
person.stream.filter(p -> account.filter().anymatch(a -> a.getName().equals(p.getName()).collect(Collectors.tolist()).forEach(p ->{ account.forEach({a ->
if(p.getName().equals(a.getName()){
p.setAge(a.getAge());
p.setAddress(a.getAddress());
}
})
})

Comment: Refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490418/iterating-and-filtering-two-lists-using-java-8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Name of the person is unique, you can use the following code:

```
Map<String, Account> accountHolders = new HashMap<>();
for(Account account : accounts) {
    accountHolders.put(account.getAccountHolderName(), account);
}
for(Person person : persons) {
    if(accountHolders.containsKey(person.getName())) {
        person.setAge(accountHolders.get(person.getName()).getAge());
        person.setAddress(accountHolders.get(person.getName()).getAddress());
    }
}
```

However this is not the best way to do it because in practice I think you can have different Persons with same name.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will update Person with Account info. I didn't bother with creating getters and setters for my test classes.

```
persons.stream().forEach( p -> {
    accounts.stream().filter(a -> a.name.equals(p.name)).findFirst().ifPresent(a -> {
        p.address = a.address;
        p.age = a.age; 
    });
});
```